# Tailwind CSS negative translate on a before element

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to center a before pseudo element relative to its parent and I'm wondering whether there is a tailwind syntax to apply negative values to the translation of the before element.

My div looks like

```html
<div class="relative before:absolute before:content-['centered'] before:left-1/2">
    I'm a div and my before element is perfectly centered
</div>
```

I would like to use something like `before:-translate-x-1/2` or `-before:translate-x-1/2` but this does not seem to work.

I can work around by defining an extra `center` class like

```css
.center::before{
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this using only tailwind utility classes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you can do `before:-translate-x-1/2`.

If you have a similar issue, for me the fix was that for some reason the tailwind layer base was commented out so some utilities didn't work.